# Fail to install pystan

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, installation

C++ compiler has been installed
However, manual installation of pystan in CMD will show the following prompts:"Cython>=0.22 and Numpy are required"

[image]

But cython and numpy have already been installed and the version is correct. I don't know why this prompt will appear...

I can't use "pip install pystan" either. There's a "failed building wheel for wheel" error.
Later installed on anaconda:

[image]

Successful operation, but still not successful installation:
"No module named'pystan'still appears after running"import pystan"
I've worked for nearly three hours to solve it!!! Asking for help

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.7(64-bit)

Comment: Can you open a python3 shell and enter `import pip`, does it give you any errors?

Comment: OK,but it work fine...

Comment: If no errors, try running the CMD `python -m pip install Cython`

Comment: Are you using the Anaconda installation instructions given here? https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html . Note in particular the platform requirements i.e., C++ compiler. Note also that unfortunately issues can arise when `conda` and `pip` are used together to create an environment, especially when the tools are used back-to-back multiple times, establishing a state that can be hard to reproduce.

Comment: fwiw, I'd stick with installing via anaconda if on windows, and not switching back & forth between `pip install` and `conda install`...  https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Comment: @michael Honestly, I would too, but in this case I would just use pip, especially since the import command didn't give the OP any errors, we know pip is installed, and it can take care of the dependencies needed as well. Perhaps the OP is not familiar installing with pip.

Comment: The issue is that `pip` won't take care of the non-python dependencies; if on linux, we can easily fall back to the system package manager to install these, but on windows, using `conda` as a package manager for non-python (i.e,. C) dependencies is an easy way to get started; otherwise, one has to install these dependencies manually, which does require a little more intimate familiarity with what's going on behind the curtain.

Comment: Thank you@GKE@michael. I've installed pystan successfully, but when I executed "pip install fbprophet", It made an error again.:"failed building wheel for fbprophet". So werid....